# How to fix "ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData:"

Tags: bash, google-chrome, ubuntu, alias

Trying to run alias command that should open two tabs in chrome via bash in Ubuntu.

```
alias mb="google-chrome url; google-chrome url"
```

After executing the alias, I will get this error message:

```
[1520:1520:0822/202900.742938:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(369)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[1520:1520:0822/202900.838165:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
```

Since this is some kind of gpu problem I tried params:

```
--disable-gpu
--disable-software-rasterizer
```

Neither of them worked.

Expected result: two tabs in one browser will open.

Actual result: One tab will open, command will get stuck on error message and second tab will not open. Process has to be killed manually.

Comment: I get the same second error message starting Spotify on Debian using awesome window manager, but not the first. `[0929/103406.292583:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this error did not appear in my .xsession-errors when I started Xorg with

```
/usr/bin/startx -- -extension GLX
```

Got this from this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408582/how-to-disable-hardware-acceleration-in-linux.